# подскажите как реализовать шаблон класса массив C++

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

В C++. Создать шаблон класса массив с методом сортировки, отсортировать свой класс “Адрес” по его полям город, улица, индекс. Не могу понять как это реализовать, что должен принимать класс массив?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно ли нужен шаблон, если тип "Адрес" четко определен?

Заведите внутри вашего класса массив типа "Адрес" и метод `sort()`, который будет сортировать этот массив. Подозреваю, что поля адреса будут строками, тогда сортируйте их по алфавиту, сначала принимание город. Если город окажется одинаков, то смотрите улицу, потом - индекс.

Comment: Ок, спасибо !! Я попробую так реализовать !

Comment: Мне кажется вы тоже не совсем верно поняли задание. Тут вроде как бы 2 задания. 1 - создать свой шаблонный класс - массив с методом сортировки, то есть абстрактную штуку которая собирает и сортирует данные. 2 - это как бы использовать этот класс, создать экземпляр этого класса - "адрес", с сортировкой по улицам.

Comment: @AndreyGolikov Почему? По поводу реализации класса не вижу противоречий. Здесь напрашивается абстрактный шаблонный класс.

Comment: Вероятно я Вас не понял или Вы меня. Мне кажется что ответом на данное задание является 2 кода. Первый код - шаблонный класс массив с сортировкой. Второй код - использование шаблонного класса на примере массива объектов адрес, с вызовом метода сортировки и тому подобное.... Если Вы имели в виду тоже самое, тоды ой:)

Comment: @AndreyGolikov По поводу шаблона я как раз уточнял. По-моему, шаблон здесь для подробностей хранения, а для сортировки более применительно наследование. Что-то вроде http://codepaste.net/ij5xt7

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю что должно быть что-то типа

```
template <class a_type> class MyTemplateClass 
{
  MyTemplateClass(uint size) : ArraySize(size); 
  ...
  const int ArraySize;
  a_type ClassArray[ArraySize];
  ...
  int SortClass(int (*compare_function)(a_type el1, atype el2));
  ...  
};
```

если нигде с синтаксисом не напутал, то это класс который может принять любой тип данных и сложить их у себя в массив, а также он может этот массив отсортировать приняв функцию сравнения 2 типов. Функцию сортировки вам надо будет реализовать.

Потом вы делаете еще один класс который содержит адрес, улицу, индекс, город. 
Делаете функцию сравнения 2 элементов этого класса. И дальше делаете массив на основе вашего первого шаблона, передав в качестве типа данных ваш класс адрес

Я бы так трактовал это задание

Comment: ArraySize(size) - это глобальная переменная или поле класса, и что мне передавать в неё (Размер чего ?).

Comment: ну тут уже на ваше усмотрение. Я описал ее как константное поле класса, которое в конструкторе класса инициализируется. Но это ваше задание, так что можете придумать свою архитектуру.

Comment: Спасибо ! Буду пробовать